# Not able to print a value in C

Tags: c

Hi am very new to c programming. I have the following piece of code, the code basically gets values from the user through the terminal and print out the values. So i have a get function and print function. Somehow, when after I key in the student id, the program stops and directly show the enrollment option prompt and print out the name and id. I tried to rearrange the options then it worked. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN 80

struct Student {
     char *name;               // point to a name string
     int id;                   // student number
     char *enroll;              // enrollment option: D or X
};

struct Student student1;

void getStudent(struct Student *s)
{
    printf("Type the name of the student: ");
    s->name = malloc(100);   // assume name has less than 100 letters 
    fgets(s->name, 100, stdin);

    printf("\nType the student numner: ");
    scanf("%d", &(s->id));

    printf("\nType the student enrollment option (D or X): ");
    scanf("%c", (s->enroll)); // some bug here
    return; 
}

void printStudent(struct Student s)
{
    char name[MAX_LEN];
    char enroll[MAX_LEN];
    int id;

    s.id = id;
    s.name = name;
    s.enroll = enroll;

    printf("Student Details: %d %s %s \n", s.id, s.name, s.enroll );
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    getStudent(&student1);
    printStudent(student1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a good time to introduce yourself to the debugger

Comment: `scanf("%c", (s->enroll));` invokes *undefined behavior* - you haven't allocated any memory for `enroll` (or initialized the pointer) - maybe you meant to declare `enroll` as `char enroll` (non-pointer)

Comment: *it worked* ..what is your question then?

Comment: There is still a line feed remaining in the stream.  When you ask to read a character, you get that one.

Comment: i would like to know why its worked when i rearrange it

Comment: Why not use character array for name in the structure. Saves the effort of using `malloc`

Comment: This code knows nothing about a "terminal".  Learn early not to conflate stdin with a tty.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the corrections in the code. http://ideone.com/BQjS1A

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN 80

// ****  Add a constant for the size of name
#define MAX_NAME 100

struct Student {
     char name[MAX_NAME];    // ** Save the hassle using malloc
     int id;                   // student number
     char enroll;    // *** Just need a character - not a character pointer
};

struct Student student1;

void getStudent(struct Student *s)
{
    printf("Type the name of the student: ");
// *** Do not need malloc as using an array
//    s->name = malloc(100);   // assume name has less than 100 letters 
    fgets(s->name, MAX_NAME, stdin);

    printf("\nType the student number: ");  // ** Corrected a typo
    scanf("%d", &(s->id));  // *** You should check the return value here and take appropriate action - I leave that you the reader

    printf("\nType the student enrollment option (D or X): ");
   // *** Added a space in front of %c to read white space
    scanf(" %c", &(s->enroll)); //  scanf requires a charcter pointer here
//    return;   This is not needed
}

void printStudent(struct Student s)
{
// *** THIS CODE DOES NOT MAKE ANY SENSE
//    char name[MAX_LEN];
//    char enroll[MAX_LEN];
//    int id;

//    s.id = id;
//    s.name = name;
//    s.enroll = enroll;
// *** Need %c to print enroll
    printf("Student Details: %d %s %c \n", s.id, s.name, s.enroll );
 ///   return;  Not needed
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    getStudent(&student1);
    printStudent(student1);
    return 0;
}
```